# PHP - Zip extract fail

Tags: php

I am having this error when extracting zip files. It says file exists but I don't think it is. Because a directory is created based on the `uniqid()` in php per upload.

```
Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo() [<a href='ziparchive.extractto'>ziparchive.extractto</a>]: File exists
```

What i am doing is upload a zip file and extract contents to another directory
 here is my code

```
function extract_files($file, $destination) {
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
    if (!is_dir($destination)) {
        mkdir($destination);
    }
    if (is_dir($destination)) {
        $zip->extractTo($destination . '/');
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If course it exists. You create the dir if it doesn't exists a few lines up

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($destination);`? is it different every time? does the directory get created?

Comment: yes it is different every time. The directory is created. Here is what happens there is a folder inside the zip file. The said folder is created but the contents aren't.